# Prevent registering multiple KafkaListener with same id for same topic

Tags: spring-kafka

If I - by mistake - create multiple KafkaListeners for the same topic (with same group id), one of them is picked randomly and the other one is ignored (which leads to sipped events).

Is there some way how to prevent this? I'd expect to get some error when trying to register multiple listeners for single topic with same group.

If somebody new comes to our team, he tries to implement handler for new event, but he misses that there already is KafkaListener for such topic, he creates another one.

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "A", groupId = "${aplicationId}")
public class TopicAEventHandler {}

@KafkaListener(topics = "B", groupId = "${aplicationId}")
public class TopicBEventHandler {}

// I want to prevent this:
@Component
@KafkaListener(topics = "A", groupId = "${aplicationId}")
public class AnotherTopicAEventHandler{}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `@KafkaListener` `id` instead of `groupId` (the `group.id` will be set to  the `id` if there is no `groupId` property).

The framework prevents registration of multiple listeners with the same `id`.

**EDIT**

Another solution:

If you are using Spring Boot, you could add an `ApplicationRunner` bean that iterates over the listener containers and checks the `groupId` and `topic` `ContainerProperties` and compare them with the expected set; throw an exception if the expectations are not matched. If you are not using Spring Boot, you can do the same in a `SmartLifecycle` bean (in the `start()` method).

```java
@Bean
public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry) {
    return args -> {
        List<String> containers = registry.getListenerContainers().stream()
                .filter(container -> container.getContainerProperties().getGroupId().equals("so62196125"))
                .map(container -> container.toString())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        if (containers.size() > 2) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected containers in group so62196125: " + containers);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Im not sure how to set those ids within single application. Can i set all ids to = "${aplicationId}"?
If each listener has to have unique id, then in order to catch issue i'm describing above, i'd have to make sure to set the same id for TopicAEventHandler and for AnotherTopicAEventHandler (and I would have to know about both of them in the first place which is the root cause of my problem)

Comment: Yes, you can use placeholders in the `id` property. We can only detect duplicate `id`s in the same application though; if you want `id="A"` and `id="B"` to use the same group id, you would need to set the `groupId` too. I generally don't advise doing that because if, say, you stop `B`, it will cause a rebalance on `A` - even though its topic is not really involved. It's generally best to use a different group for each listener.

Comment: But different groups means that listeners would be in different consumer groups-so they would consume topic multiple times. 
What i'd like to do is to ensure that single topic is consumed just once within application-and that there is single KafkaListener for it. If I'd try to register another one I'd like to get error. 
So,the only way I can achieve it is by having the same id when declaring KafkaListener (that would throw some error). 
So when registering new handler I'd have to set the same id in order to get that error- if i'd set diferent id, I'd get another consumer). 
Is it correct?

Comment: Yes; see `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.registerListenerContainer()`. But you first listener is consuming from a different topic to the second one. Putting them in different groups will not affect how they receive records. Putting them in the same group means they will go through unnecessary rebalances.

Comment: Oh, you mean putting setting different group for TopicAEventHandler and TopicBEventHandler. That I can do.
But about the original issue - there is practically no "automatic" way hot to prevent new developer for creating AnotherTopicAEventHandler. He would have to "guess" the same id as in TopicAEventHandler in order to get error. If he'd set different id, there would be no error - and I would have two handlers (if they have same groupId - only one of them would be processing events, if they have different groupIds - they both would proces events).

Comment: If you are using Spring Boot, you could add an `ApplicationRunner` bean that iterates over the listener containers and checks the `groupId` and `topic` `ContainerProperties` and compare them with the expected set; throw an exception if the expectations are not matched. If you are not using Spring Boot, you can do the same in a `SmartLifecycle` bean (in the `start()` method).